# Reduction from 'combination with repetition' to 'permutation with repetition'

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, solution-verification, combinations

The combination with repetition can be written as follows:

$$\left(\!\!\binom{n}{r}\!\!\right) = \binom{n+r-1}{r}$$

This formula can be deduced by considering a system that gives an equivalent number of cases of mixing - a system in which there are $n-1$ identical dividers and $r$ identical objects.

I thought, what if we say that the objects are not identical (where dividers are still identical)? Then can we not reduce this to the permutation with repetition, $n^r$?

I actually used an analogy to come up with the above idea - $n$ menus in a restaurant and food for $r$ people is to be served and we are finding the number of combinations of menus, without considering who gets to eat what. So, if we don't think of the objects as being identical, then it is same as caring **who** eats what.

But the following formula, $$\binom{n+r-1}{r} \times r! = \frac{(n+r-1)!}{r! \times (n-1)!} \times r!$$ $$= \frac{(n+r-1)!}{(n-1)!} = (n+r-1) \times (n+r-2)\times ... \times (n+1) \times n$$ does not seem to lead to the expression $n^r$.

I think I considered who gets what well, but what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using $r!$ as the factor to pass from combinations to permutations, however not every combination has $r!$ permutations you can create from it.

The problem is that there can be repetitions on the menus  : compare the case where all the people get different menus and the case where there are two people receiving the same menus.

Comment: Is it because if there are two people receiving the same menu, then we have to consider the fact that order does not matter within a specific menu? For example person A wants sandwich, and persons B and C want chicken then we have to use $3! / 2!$ instead of $3!$.

Comment: And we have to consider that for every single combination of people A, B, C?

Comment: yes, exactly ! :)